# How to define multiple events in serverless?

Tags: amazon-s3, serverless-framework, serverless, aws-serverless

I want to set multiple events to a function in serverless.js framework.

Now the function is getting triggered from all object create events,

```
init:
    handler: src/functions/main/handler.run
    timeout: 900
    events:
      - s3:
          bucket: IMAGE_BUCKET_NAME
          event: s3:ObjectCreated:*
```

But I only want to trigger for `s3:ObjectCreated:Put`, `s3:ObjectCreated:Post` and `s3:ObjectCreated:CompleteMultipartUpload`, how can I modify the yaml?

Comment: https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/s3#triggering-separate-functions-from-the-same-bucket

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me,

```
init:
    handler: src/functions/main/handler.startStepFunction
    timeout: 900
    events:
      - s3:
          bucket: IMAGE_BUCKET_NAME
          event: s3:ObjectCreated:Put
      - s3:
          bucket: IMAGE_BUCKET_NAME
          event: s3:ObjectCreated:Post
      - s3:
          bucket: IMAGE_BUCKET_NAME
          event: s3:ObjectCreated:CompleteMultipartUpload
```